# Timesheet.js: Background and label/boarder color

Tags: javascript, html, css, timesheet.js

I´m using timesheet.js from https://github.com/sbstjn/timesheet.js to display a nice and simple timeline.

I want to change the background color to white but when I change background-color:#333 to background-color:#FFFFFF in timesheet.css the lines/boarders and the year labels aren´t visible anymore. I can´t find the color options for them. Could someone please help me? Thank you.

Original:

[image: Original]

White Background:

[image: White Background]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Timesheet.js</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/timesheet.css'>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="timesheet"></div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../js/timesheet.js'></script><script  src="../js/timesheet-script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**timesheet.css**

```
.timesheet{width:auto;height:auto;margin:0 auto}.timesheet{border-top:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.5);background-color:#333;position:relative}.timesheet.color-scheme-default .bubble-default{background-color:RGBA(252, 70, 74, 1)}.timesheet.color-scheme-default .bubble-lorem{background-color:RGBA(154, 202, 39, 1)}.timesheet.color-scheme-default .bubble-ipsum{background-color:RGBA(60, 182, 227, 1)}.timesheet.color-scheme-default .bubble-dolor{background-color:RGBA(244, 207, 48, 1)}.timesheet.color-scheme-default .bubble-sit{background-color:RGBA(169, 105, 202, 1)}.timesheet.color-scheme-alternative .bubble-default{background-color:#f3552e}.timesheet.color-scheme-alternative .bubble-lorem{background-color:#88c33a}.timesheet.color-scheme-alternative .bubble-ipsum{background-color:#436ae0}.timesheet.color-scheme-alternative .bubble-dolor{background-color:#f4d234}.timesheet.color-scheme-alternative .bubble-sit{background-color:#707d86}.timesheet .scale{height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;float:left}.timesheet .scale section{float:left;width:59px;text-align:center;color:rgba(250,250,250,0.8);font-family:"Signika Negative";font-size:13px;line-height:24px;font-weight:lighter;border-left:1px dashed rgba(250,250,250,0.2);height:100%}.timesheet .data{margin:28px 0 0 0;padding:0;text-align:left;list-style-type:none;color:rgba(250,250,250,0.8);font-family:"Signika Negative";font-size:13px;overflow:hidden}.timesheet .data li{margin:0 0 3px 0;line-height:22px;height:21px;display:block;clear:both;position:relative;white-space:nowrap}.timesheet .data li:hover .bubble{opacity:1}.timesheet .data li .date{color:#b5b5b5;font-size:14px}.timesheet .data li .label{font-weight:lighter;font-size:14px;padding-left:5px;line-height:21px;color:#979796;white-space:nowrap}.timesheet .data li .bubble{width:24px;height:7px;display:block;float:left;position:relative;top:7px;border-radius:4px;margin:0 10px 0 0;opacity:0.7}#timesheet-alternative{background-color:RGBA(247, 247, 247, 1);border-radius:5px}#timesheet-alternative section{color:RGBA(63, 68, 72, 1);border-left:1px dashed RGBA(63, 68, 72, 0.2)}#timesheet-alternative section:first-child{border-left:1px dashed transparent}#timesheet-alternative .date{display:none}#timesheet-alternative .bubble{margin-right:7px}#timesheet-alternative .label{padding-left:0px;color:RGBA(48, 48, 48, 1)}
```

**timesheet.js**

```
!function(){"use strict";var Bubble=function(wMonth,min,start,end){this.min=min,this.start=start,this.end=end,this.widthMonth=wMonth};Bubble.prototype.formatMonth=function(num){return num=parseInt(num,10),num>=10?num:"0"+num},Bubble.prototype.getStartOffset=function(){return this.widthMonth/12*(12*(this.start.getFullYear()-this.min)+this.start.getMonth())},Bubble.prototype.getFullYears=function(){return(this.end&&this.end.getFullYear()||this.start.getFullYear())-this.start.getFullYear()},Bubble.prototype.getMonths=function(){var fullYears=this.getFullYears(),months=0;return this.end?this.end.hasMonth?(months+=this.end.getMonth()+1,months+=12-(this.start.hasMonth?this.start.getMonth():0),months+=12*(fullYears-1)):(months+=12-(this.start.hasMonth?this.start.getMonth():0),months+=12*(fullYears-1>0?fullYears-1:0)):months+=this.start.hasMonth?1:12,months},Bubble.prototype.getWidth=function(){return this.widthMonth/12*this.getMonths()},Bubble.prototype.getDateLabel=function(){return[(this.start.hasMonth?this.formatMonth(this.start.getMonth()+1)+"/":"")+this.start.getFullYear(),this.end?"-"+((this.end.hasMonth?this.formatMonth(this.end.getMonth()+1)+"/":"")+this.end.getFullYear()):""].join("")},window.TimesheetBubble=Bubble}(),function(){"use strict";var Timesheet=function(container,min,max,data){this.data=[],this.year={min:min,max:max},this.parse(data||[]),"undefined"!=typeof document&&(this.container="string"==typeof container?document.querySelector("#"+container):container,this.drawSections(),this.insertData())};Timesheet.prototype.insertData=function(){for(var html=[],widthMonth=this.container.querySelector(".scale section").offsetWidth,n=0,m=this.data.length;m>n;n++){var cur=this.data[n],bubble=new TimesheetBubble(widthMonth,this.year.min,cur.start,cur.end),line=['<span style="margin-left: '+bubble.getStartOffset()+"px; width: "+bubble.getWidth()+'px;" class="bubble bubble-'+(cur.type||"default")+'" data-duration="'+(cur.end?Math.round((cur.end-cur.start)/1e3/60/60/24/39):"")+'"></span>','<span class="date">'+bubble.getDateLabel()+"</span> ",'<span class="label">'+cur.label+"</span>"].join("");html.push("<li>"+line+"</li>")}this.container.innerHTML+='<ul class="data">'+html.join("")+"</ul>"},Timesheet.prototype.drawSections=function(){for(var html=[],c=this.year.min;c<=this.year.max;c++)html.push("<section>"+c+"</section>");this.container.className="timesheet color-scheme-alternative",this.container.innerHTML='<div class="scale">'+html.join("")+"</div>"},Timesheet.prototype.parseDate=function(date){return-1===date.indexOf("/")?(date=new Date(parseInt(date,10),0,1),date.hasMonth=!1):(date=date.split("/"),date=new Date(parseInt(date[1],10),parseInt(date[0],10)-1,1),date.hasMonth=!0),date},Timesheet.prototype.parse=function(data){for(var n=0,m=data.length;m>n;n++){var beg=this.parseDate(data[n][0]),end=4===data[n].length?this.parseDate(data[n][1]):null,lbl=4===data[n].length?data[n][2]:data[n][1],cat=data[n][3]||"default";beg.getFullYear()<this.year.min&&(this.year.min=beg.getFullYear()),end&&end.getFullYear()>this.year.max?this.year.max=end.getFullYear():beg.getFullYear()>this.year.max&&(this.year.max=beg.getFullYear()),this.data.push({start:beg,end:end,label:lbl,type:cat})}},window.Timesheet=Timesheet}();
```

**timesheet-script.js**

```
new Timesheet('timesheet', 2002, 2011, [
  ['2003', '09/2003', 'A freaking awesome time', 'lorem'],
  ['06/2003', '09/2003', 'Some great memories', 'ipsum'],
  ['2003', 'Had very bad luck'],
  ['10/2003', '2006', 'At least had fun', 'dolor'],
  ['02/2005', '05/2006', 'Enjoyed those times as well', 'ipsum'],
  ['07/2005', '09/2005', 'Bad luck again', 'default'],
  ['10/2005', '2008', 'For a long time nothing happened', 'dolor'],
  ['01/2008', '05/2009', 'LOST Season #4', 'lorem'],
  ['01/2009', '05/2009', 'LOST Season #4', 'lorem'],
  ['02/2010', '05/2010', 'LOST Season #5', 'lorem'],
  ['09/2008', '06/2010', 'FRINGE #1 & #2', 'ipsum']
]);
```

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jimkennelly/krgkra4o/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS your custom CSS file

```
.timesheet {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: #fff;
}
.timesheet .scale section {

    color: #000;
    border-left: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
.timesheet .data li .date {
    color: #333;
}
.timesheet .data li .label {
    color: #333;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/4mwj3169/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can chance `background-color:#333` to `background-color:#fff` and add `color: #000`

```css
.timesheet{width:auto;height:auto;margin:0 auto}
.timesheet{
border-top:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
background-color:#fff;
color : #000;
position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="timesheet">
Hello there!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your code the lines/boarders and the year labels 
are unfortunately not visible either. I get exactly the same result as before :(